# PayPal Smart Button updated via Ajax

Tags: javascript, iframe, paypal

I have a shopping cart which is updated via Ajax (quantity, removing of products). How do I update the value in the Smart Button iframe? It obviously works  when I refresh the page, but how to do it in the background with Ajax? I have tried reloading the PayPal iframe using a hack which bypasses the same origin policy but it didn't work, the Smart Button disappeared.
This is the hack I'm talking about:

```
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.src = iframe.src
```

This is my Smart Button code:

```
<script>   
  paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
      shape: "rect",
      color: "gold",
      layout: "horizontal",
      label: "checkout",
      size: "responsive",
      tagline: "false"
  },
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            currency_code: "GBP",
            value: <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?>
          },
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        alert("Dear " + details.payer.name.given_name + ", Thank you for your payment!");
      });
    },
    onShippingChange: function(data, actions) {
      if (data.shipping_address.country_code !== "GB") {
        return actions.reject();
      }
      return actions.resolve();
    }
  }).render("#paypal-button-container");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Post more information about your actual PayPal button code and its createOrder function in particular, so we can give the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
value: <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?>
```

To call a JavaScript function, which you will need to write and serve as part of the page

```
value: getCartTotal()
```

Somewhere, perhaps at the top of the `<script>`, you will have something like:

```
window.myCartTotal = '<?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?>';
function getCartTotal() {
  return window.myCartTotal;
}
```

Then have your AJAX also update window.myCartTotal

There are many more elegant ways to code this, but that should get you going.

---

### The proper server-side solution

For best results you shouldn't be setting the amount on the client side's createOrder, and perhaps even more importantly not capturing on the client side. Doing these things on the client side opens you to a whole series of issues and problems. Instead, have the client side call two routes on your server, one for 'Create Transaction' and another for 'Set Up Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Then, use those two new routes following button approval code's ajax/fetch calls: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thanks very much. This looks good. I'm just not sure how to update `window.myCartTotal` with Ajax. For example when I use Ajax to remove a product from the basket I then replace the "old" html of `total price` with a new response from the server, for example: `$(".total-amount").html($(".total-amount", res).html());` I'm not sure if this is what I should do with window.myCartTotal. By the way, in the above code `<?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?>` becomes a global variable, doesn't it?

Comment: You'll still want to update the HTML of the page as you are. If res is a number, `window.myCartTotal = res;` , or obtain/extract the number as needed

Comment: Also updated answer with information on a proper server-side integration, so you know how things should be done

Comment: Got it finally. My AJAX update of `window.myCartTotal`: `window.myCartTotal = Math.round(parseInt($(".total-amount", res).html().replace("£", ""))); ` I was getting the updated value but in a wrong format (with decimals and the £ symbol). For some reason `value` in the Smart Button would accept decimal numbers when the PHP code was there but not when the number was inserted by calling `getCartTotal()`.

Comment: I thought that getting the value in the Smart Button with a PHP code was enough as it is taken from the server, not the client side.

Comment: PayPal receives it from the client side, so no it is not enough

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Will definitely go for the server side implementation. What's the purpose of a client side implementation if it's not secure?

Comment: For people who don't have access to a server, or do but are unwilling or unable to do things well